# Where can I find the dimensions and weight of a game?

Tags: storage

I eant to order some games from the USA (I live outside the US).
Is there an online store or some other site that specifies the dimensions and weight of a board game or the entire order and not just the shipping fee before checkout?

Thank You.

Comment: Try amazon.com for starters. Example: [Race for the galaxy](http://www.amazon.com/Rio-Grande-Games-Race-Galaxy/dp/B000YLAOEW/), Product Dimensions: 8 x 2.5 x 12 inches. Shipping Weight: 1.5 pounds.

Answer (score 7):

Check with [Board Game Geek](http://boardgamegeek.com).  On pages for games, they have a list of all versions with the size and weight.  For example, see [this entry for Race for the Galaxy](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/28143/race-for-the-galaxy#versions).  It states that pretty much all versions are 10.83 x 7.48 x 2.56 inches and 1.44 lbs.  Other games should also have version sections with similar information.